Using vector with strings in mutate with paste
I am trying to build an ID in a tibble with "paste" and a vector with the column names as strings:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~PERIOD, ~CODE, ~VALUE,
  1995, "A", 10,
  1996, "B", 20
)
df

mygroup <- c("PERIOD", "CODE")

I would like to have this result
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  PERIOD CODE  VALUE ID    
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1   1995 A        10 1995_A
2   1996 B        20 1996_B

Of course the following code doesn't do what I want
df %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste(mygroup, collapse = "_"))

as it produces
  PERIOD CODE  VALUE ID         
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
1   1995 A        10 PERIOD_CODE
2   1996 B        20 PERIOD_CODE

I have tried with !! and curly braces, but nothing worked.

Some answers are equal to those in the linked duplicate answer.

Using base R. The code is concise and tractable but will be inefficient if mygroup is very long. Use do.call() instead.
df$ID <- Reduce(\(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "_"), df[mygroup])

#   PERIOD CODE  VALUE ID    
#    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1   1995 A        10 1995_A
# 2   1996 B        20 1996_B

Another concise but inefficient solution:
df$ID <- apply(df[mygroup], 1, paste, collapse = "_")


You can try
df %>%
  mutate(ID = do.call(paste, c(.[mygroup], sep = "_")))

or
df %>%
  mutate(ID = do.call(str_c, c(select(., mygroup), sep = "_")))

which gives
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  PERIOD CODE  VALUE ID
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1   1995 A        10 1995_A
2   1996 B        20 1996_B


As you are loading tidyverse, I think the natural way to do this is using tidyr::unite(), a convenience function to paste together multiple columns into one, and the !!! splice operator to inject the column names passed dynamically.
df |>
    unite(
        "ID", !!!mygroup,
        remove = FALSE # don't delete the pasted columns
    )

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   ID     PERIOD CODE  VALUE
#   <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 1995_A   1995 A        10
# 2 1996_B   1996 B        20


Another possible tidyverse flavour:
df %>%
 mutate(ID = pmap_chr(across(all_of(mygroup)), ~ paste(..., sep = "_")))

  PERIOD CODE  VALUE ID    
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1   1995 A        10 1995_A
2   1996 B        20 1996_B


Maybe something like this?
 df %>%
      mutate(id = paste(eval(parse(text = mygroup[1])),
                        eval(parse(text = mygroup[2])), sep = "_"))
    
    # A tibble: 2 × 4
      PERIOD CODE  VALUE id    
       <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
    1   1995 A        10 1995_A
    2   1996 B        20 1996_B

